# Added Vite Proxy Server for Axios call in vite.conf.js, and it does not work after build

Tags: api, axios, cors, vuejs3, vite

Calling API with Axios was resulting CORS error. One solution I found was to use a proxy server. So I added the proxy server like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/myapi': {
        target: 'https://api.ipify.org',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/myapi/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This solution worked in localhost just fine, but after I built it and deployed, it no longer recognized /myapi anymore. Like it does not exists.
How can I make it work so that I will work on the deployment too?

I tried a lot of alternate ways of avaoiding proxy server, but could not overcome CORS.

This is how I'm calling the API in my component:

```
async getUserData() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/myapi?format=json');
        return response.data.ip;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch IP address');
    }
}
```